# Calculate Field gives ERROR 002717: Invalid Arcade expression, Arcade Error: Index out of bounds

Tags: arcgis-pro, field-calculator, arcade, error-002717

I've tried this expression in the [Arcade playground](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/playground/) and it works as I expect.

`Number(Split($feature.PVI,"+")[1])`

$feature.PVI is a text field that contains something that looks like "R+15".

What should be entered into the field is `15`. When I try to use the same expression in the Calculate Field tool I get `ERROR 002717: Invalid Arcade expression, Arcade Error: Index out of bounds`.

Comment: What were the precise steps that you used to test this in the Arcade Playground?  I just tried it for the first time by copy/pasting your expression into it and clicking Test and I got `Execution Error:Runtime Error: Identifier Not Found. $feature`.

Comment: Under Globals->Constraints you can set ```$feature.name1``` to R+21. You'd have to use the expression ```Number(Split($feature.name1,"+")[1])```. But the expression also works in Playground if you just substitute the string "R+21" for ```$feature.name1```.  ```$feature.PVI``` comes from my actual project in Arc.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: if PVI is "R+15" then your code works, which strongly suggest PVI does not always contain a "+".

Answer (score 2):

I was implementing something very similar today, and getting **ERROR 002717: Invalid Arcade expression, Arcade error: Index out of bounds** as well. Same situation, where the "split()" function was working as expected in [the arcade playground](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/playground/), but I was getting the above error while trying to set up a "Constraint" type Attribute Rule for a feature class in a local file geodatabase.

But, I had success using negative indexing. Instead of:

```
// where a field's value might look like "3:47"
var arrayHoursMinutes = Split($feature.Hiking_Time, ":")
var hrs = arrayHoursMinutes[0]   //this seems fine...
var mins = arrayHoursMinutes[1]  //this causes an error...
```

I was able to use this for the third line, where the first two are the same:

```
var mins = arrayHoursMinutes[-1]
```

Obviously this would only be helpful if you were grabbing your first and last value (which is fine when there are only two in the array).

Answer (score 1):

At [ERROR 002717: Invalid Arcade expression, Arcade error: Index out of bounds](https://community.esri.com/t5/attribute-rules-questions/error-002717-invalid-arcade-expression-arcade/m-p/1222706#M610) I was getting the same error message as you when using Arcade with ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2, a file geodatabase and Add Attribute Rule.

My Arcade code was:

```
var arrName = split($feature.RouteName,'_');
return Number(arrName[1],'####KM') + (Geometry($feature).paths[-1][-1].m/10000)
```

and you will see that the Split function was being used like in your question.

It was important for me to get this attribute rule working so I worked around it by using the Mid function instead:

```
return Number(Mid($feature.RouteName,8,4)) + ($feature.END_M/10000)
```

Note that $feature.END_M had already been set using:

```
Geometry($feature).paths[-1][-1].m
```

in a preceding attribute rule.

I think there may be a bug in how Arcade's Split function is being employed by some ArcGIS Pro tools but until that can be confirmed and fixed you may need to look for a workaround.